# TContent organizer email

Tags: content-organizer

In our application we use the content organizer to re-route incoming documents. We have set the timerjob Content Organizer Processing on 1 minute for fast processing. However users now get every minute an email when a document is not ready and need more information.

Is there a way that a document is automatically routed on saving the document without setting the timerjob settings on 1 minute?

Comment: Solved my problem. Problem was a custom field. This field override the SPContext.Current.FormContext.OnSaveHandler eventhandler. Now the documents are instantly routed onsave and the timerjob is set run 2 a day.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could think of is to add an item event receiver to your document library. When a new document gets added, start the Content Organizer Processing timer job manually.

```
public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        using(SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
        {
            site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions["RouterProcessingJob"].RunNow();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could route the file yourself

```
public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        EcmDocumentRoutingWeb contentOrganizerWeb = new EcmDocumentRoutingWeb(properties.Web);
        if (!contentOrganizerWeb.IsRoutingEnabled)
            return;

        string finalDestination;
        bool wasRoutedToOtherSite;
        contentOrganizerWeb.Router.RouteFileToFinalDestination(properties.ListItem, out finalDestination, out wasRoutedToOtherSite);    
    }
}
```

However, these may not be ideal because they would require you to add the receiver to every document library.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.recordsmanagement.recordsrepository.ecmdocumentrouter.aspx

Comment: I am getting an error on contentOrganizerWeb.Router.RouteFileToFinalDestination(properties.ListItem, out finalDestination, out wasRoutedToOtherSite);

Comment: I did not have the time to set up an environment and test that. I think that you could explore doing the routing yourself through a receiver though. It may take some work to get it functioning. What was the error message by the way?

Comment: I am getting  Object reference not set to an instance of an object  at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRouter.RouteFileToFinalDestination(SPListItem itemToRoute, String& finalDestination, Boolean& wasRoutedToOtherSite)
   at CZ.SharePoint.ContentOrganizerReceiver.RunContentOrganizer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ItemUpdated>b__0()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)